# A link on my website is hijacked?

Tags: html

I have a web site at sportdata.com.au. Most of the second level pages have a "home" link on the menu which is set like

```
<a href="http://sportdata.com.au">sportdata</a>
```

If I click on the link, I am incorrectly sent to software.com.au but the link should go to sportdata.com.au and the page source is correct. The problem does not occur on my index page but on each of the lower pages.

If you check the page source you can see that its correct as above but still goes to the wrong URL.

A previous typo has nothing to do with the problem and has now led folks here to believe incorrectly that's the issue.

Comment: You have a typo in the URL you show above. `sportdata.com` leads to a squatting page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In generated pages source HTML you can see the next line:

```
<td width=73><a href="http://www.software.com.au"><img src="images/but_top_home.gif" width="73" height="16" border="0" alt="sports software" ></a></td>
```

So pay attention to your source code.

Answer (score 1):

I guess sportdata.com does not exist, while sportdata.com.au does. So maybe your href attribute should read http://sportdata.com.au

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, the link on the tutorial page actually leads to software.com.au. And yes, sportdata.com/au is probably a big typo.